# KnexTimeoutError when using knex.raw()

Tags: node.js, node-modules, knex.js, node-oracledb, objection.js

My node.js app uses knex as the ORM to connect to oracledb database. I am seeing an error with knex -

```
KnexTimeoutError: Knex: Timeout acquiring a connection. The pool is probably full. Are you missing a .transacting(trx) call?
  at Client_Oracledb.acquireConnection (/app/oracle/network/node_modules/knex/lib/client.js:312:26)
  at async Runner.ensureConnection (/app/oracle/network/node_modules/knex/lib/execution/runner.js:287:28)
```

I am listing the versions of some of the packages used by my app -

knex -  2.4.2

mock-knex -  0.4.12

oracledb - 5.5.0

lightship - 9.0.2

objection - 3.0.1

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask